# phpunit testing catch block

Tags: php, exception, phpunit, try-catch

Using;
PHP 5.5
PHPUnit 3.7

I have a piece of code that holds a try/catch statement.

I'm trying to test the handling that is done in the catch block but PHP unit seems not to reach the catch block.

Tested with annotation expectedException and with

`$this->setExpectedException('InvalidArgumentException');`

But this only checks if the exception is thrown

Does anyone know how to?

Comment: Yes. Cause an exception. If it is impossible for the code to throw an exception then you found unnecessary code. Do you have code to show to give you better help?

Comment: Example for testing an exception: http://php.budgegeria.de/QvivqrGrfg